# Navigating/Iterating in object as Interface to obtain key-value pair

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

```
export interface Worker {
  salary?: number;
  manager?: boolean;
  name?: string;
  hired?: Date;
}

const worker1: Worker = { salary: 5000, manager: true, name: "Bob", birth: new Date() };
```

I need to obtain all pairs of attributes as key - value.

```
for (const [key, value] of worker1????) {
    console.log("key: '" + key + "', value: " + value); // to do other needed operations
}
```

The output expected for this log Question is :

```
key: 'salary', value: 5000
key: 'manager', value: true
key: 'name', value: Bob
key: 'birth', value: xxxxx
```

**How achieve that?**

Comment: Since all the properties are optional, what do you expect to see for `const worker2: Worker = {}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)?

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(worker1)) {
    console.log("key: '" + key + "', value: " + value);
}
```